# Trying to find a flat coordinate system on a unit sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, curvature, spheres

The metric of the surface a unit sphere is:

$$ds^2 = d\theta ^2 + \cos^2(\theta)d\phi ^2$$

I want to find a locally flat coordinate system $\theta'$ and $\phi'$ at coordinates: $\theta = \pi/4$ and $\phi = 0$

I can do that easily by assumption, but I want to work it in the following way because I am preparing for a spacetime metric in physics.

I started like how [Bence Racskó](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588551/locally-flat-understanding) started and did the translation:
$$\widetilde{\theta} = \theta - \frac{\pi}{4} $$
then followed his work and reached the following:

$$\delta_{ij}=g'_{ij}(0) = A^k_i A^l_j \widetilde{g}_{ij}(0)$$

Because I want the flat coordinates to be at $\widetilde{\theta}= 0$, then got the following equations:

$$1 = A^1_1A^1_1 + \frac{1}{2} A^2_1 A^2_1$$
$$1 = A^1_2A^1_2 + \frac{1}{2} A^2_2 A^2_2$$
$$0 = A^1_2A^1_1 + \frac{1}{2} A^2_2 A^2_1$$

But those are only 3 equalities for 4 unknowns. How should I continue?

Note that if there is another simpler but also general way I could solve this problem, I do not have a problem. My goal is to be able to transform to locally flat coordinates for any metric.

Comment: I suspect symmetry requires $A_2^1 = A_1^2$.

Comment: I thought so, but I'm not sure why. Maybe because both $\delta_{ij}$ and $\widetilde{g}_{ij}$ are diagonal.

Comment: I don't know general relativity well. "Locally flat coordinates" are polar coordinates, right? ie the coordinate chart is defined using the exponential map. If so I'd be inclined to work out polar coordinates at the north pole and then compose with the rotation from the north pole to the desired point.

Comment: What does “locally flat” mean? This is not a usual mathematical term in a curved space.

Comment: Basically, in these coordinates, the metric becomes $\delta_{ij}$ at the respective position.

Comment: OK, that’s geodesic normal coordinates based at the point. Very misleading terminology.

Comment: @Neal's comment above gives the result